# Linux Mint 15 + Rails with Apache/Passenger

Tags: web-hosting, apache2, virtualhost, ruby-on-rails

I am only beginner and try to understand how to configure apach web-server for my RubyOnRails app. I have linux, installed apache2, passenger and apache2-module for passenger. While installing i got text like this

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/rubys/.rvm/.../ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/rubys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.8
PassengerRuby /home/rubys/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby
```

I need add this to my apache config file, so, i use

```
$ apachectl -V | grep HTTPD_ROOT
$ apachectl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

file, which i need is here

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

my rails app is here

```
/home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot
```

Also i have file in /etc/apache2/**ports.conf** with text like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen80
```

What I have to copy to my **apache2.conf**? and where i have to add this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName depot.yourhost.com
   DocumentRoot /home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot
   <Directory /home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never asked a question, but looking at your data I will try to fix your potential problems, so please update the question with a real question so it better serves anyone else who may have similar issues in the future and stumbles across this question.

Try putting a space in here: `Listen80` like `Listen 80`.

Then try putting this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName depot.yourhost.com
   DocumentRoot /home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot
   <Directory /home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, add a slash `/` into this at the end:

```
<Directory /home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot/>
```

and then restart Apache.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working. But I solved my problem in another way by creating new file in /etc/apache2/sites-available' with <VirtualHost *:80>...</VirtualHost *:80> and using 'RailsEnv development' there. And also changed DocumentRoot to: /home/alexkd/WebDev/rails/depot/public